# W/CursorWrapperInner(8375): Cursor finalized without prior close()

Tags: android, resolver

I am fed up of this issue, don't know actually where is problem, Below is my code :

```
private void readSMS() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Read SMS","Called");
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    StringBuilder smsBackup = new StringBuilder(); 
    Cursor messagesCursor = cr.query(uri, new String[] { "_id","address","body","person"}, null,null, null);
    smsBackup.append("SMS Back UP (Total Message(s)::"+messagesCursor.getCount()+") \n\n");

    String name = null;
    if(messagesCursor.getCount() > 0){
        while(messagesCursor.moveToNext()){
            name = null;
            name = getName(messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("address")));

            if(name==null)
                name = "Sender : " + messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("address"));

            smsBackup.append("Sender : "+name +"\n"+  "Message : "+messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("body")) + "\n\n");
        }
    }

    Log.d("InSMS Lenght","::"+smsBackup.toString().length());
}
```

here is log cat message : W/CursorWrapperInner(8375): Cursor finalized without prior close()

Answer (score 0):

You should close the `Cursor` object once you're done working with it.

Comment: You mean above the Log.d("InSMS Lenght","::"+smsBackup.toString().length());
I have done that also forgot print here, still thats not working dear.

Answer (score 0):

This may be old but here is the reason why.

Don't throw the exception here:

```
readSMS() throws IOException
```

instead wrap in a a try catch block like so:

```
try{
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    StringBuilder smsBackup = new StringBuilder(); 
    Cursor messagesCursor = cr.query(uri, new String[] { "_id","address","body","person"}, null,null, null);
    smsBackup.append("SMS Back UP (Total Message(s)::"+messagesCursor.getCount()+") \n\n");

    String name = null;
    if(messagesCursor.getCount() > 0){
        while(messagesCursor.moveToNext()){
            name = null;
            name = getName(messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("address")));

            if(name==null)
                name = "Sender : " + messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("address"));

            smsBackup.append("Sender : "+name +"\n"+  "Message : "+messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("body")) + "\n\n");
        }
    }
 messagesCursor.close();
}catch(IOException e){
//handle here, if not log it
}finally{
//can also close here if you want, need to wrap in another try block and check for null
}
```

Seems like the problem is the ioexception is being caught before the `close()` could be called. The method is then thrown at that point and is never called. I could be wrong, I just took a quick glance at it. I hope this helps.